# Python GUI framework

Tags: python, gui, framework

I'm looking to build a GUI on top of something I wrote in Python that compares objects in one of my company's tools. Essentially it's doing a 3 way compare, and I want to be able to inspect elements, so lots of browsing through hierarchy and viewing text.

In short, I want:

- Widely used framework
- Good at browsing through hierarchical data
- Usable from Python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TkInter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) is the widely used python framework for building GUI.

For Browsing hierarchial classes or modules there are lot of extensions available for TkInter like [tix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.tix.html).

Answer (score 2):

Like BarathVutukuri said... Tkinter or my recommendation... PyQt or PySide.  The UI that can be built with PyQt is very robust.  The following post does a good comparison of Tkinter and PyQt.

[Developing GUIs in Python: Tkinter vs PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1094155/259538)

Answer (score 0):

PyGame is also a great GUI framework for python that supports a massive range of tools.

Although it is typically used to make 2D games, I have found it really useful for building simple GUIs

http://www.pygame.org/

Comment: This post does not contain enough information to be considered a quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed. Especially, answers must show how the requirements are met, what makes the product recommendable, and where to find it.